# "На более" или "более на"

Tags: склонение, грамматика

Совсем запуталась - Интернет не помог.

"Система внедрена **на более чем** 1 000 объектов"
или
"Система внедрена **более чем на** 1 000 объектов"

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во
 флективных языках, в том числе и русском, допускается практически любая
 перестановка слов в предложении. Этот стилистический прием называется 
**инверсия**. Нейтральным вариантом будет *"более чем на ..."*, но если 
хотите подчеркнуть, что именно "более", допустимо и *"на более чем ..."*.

---

Примеры из Нацкорпуса

> везде разверзались огромные ниши с уступом на более чем аршин

Андрей Белый. Африканский дневник (1922)

> Свидетельство этому ― 120 изданий на более чем 30 языках мира

Виктор Некрасов. Кому это нужно? (1974)

> 

Comment: вообще, конечно, на язык сразу просится "Более чем на"... 
Но я порассуждала и решила, что второй вариант тоже нельзя отнести к неправильным.

Comment: Инверсия здесь ни при чем. При инверсии мы перестраиваем предложение, чтобы изменить его интонационную структуру (для выделения интонационным ударением нужного слова). Здесь же речь идет о грамматике словосочетания и правильном выборе падежного окончания (см. дополнение к моему ответу).

Answer (score 2):

Есть оборот "более чем"  не "на более чем". Пример:   ***"Водка была горькая, разведенная, по случаю праздника, водой более чем на три четверти".*** В. Короленко, Сон Макара (= как минимум на три четверти, самое меньшее на три четверти, на три четверти и даже больше). Таким образом тайна была сохранена более чем полудюжиною заговорщиков. А. Пушкин, Метель(=полудюжиною и даже больше).См.здесь.http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_68  ;  http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/70/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5___%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%28%2C%29_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: ну первый пример еще как-то подходит, а второй - про заговорщиков - не тот случай....

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Система внедрена более чем на тысяче объектов.

Устойчивое выражение "более чем" стоит перед количественно-именным сочетанием (счетным оборотом), при этом не важно, в какой оно форме (предложное иди беспредложное сочетание).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Попробую доказать, что это ЕДИНСТВЕННО ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ (оно, кстати, в ЕДИНСТВЕННОМ варианте предлагается и на Грамоте.ру).

1) Именительный падеж: тысяча (И..п,) объектов  → более чем тысяча  (И.п.) объектов.

2) Предложный падеж: на тысяче (П.п.) объектов. → более чем на тысяче (П.п.) объектов.

3) На  более чем  тысяче  (П.п.) объектов – НЕВЕРНО, так как  неправильное падежное управление в  выражении «более чем тысячЕ».

Comment: 1) Именительный падеж: тысяча (И..п,) объектов → целая тысяча (И.п.) объектов.

2) Предложный падеж: на тысяче (П.п.) объектов. → целой на тысяче (П.п.) объектов.

3) На целой тысяче (П.п.) объектов – НЕВЕРНО, так как неправильное падежное управление в выражении «целой тысячЕ».

Это если вашей логикой пользоваться. Если пользоваться логикой русского языка, то если определение стоит до предлога, то оно относится ко всему словосочетанию, а если после, то только к главному слову (ср. думать более чем о друге дочери, думать о более чем друге дочери).

Comment: По Вашей логике предлог "НА" можно изъять из словосочетания и инверсировать  в любое место предложения, поэтому я даже не пытаюсь понять Ваши записки. Но все-таки давайте предоставлять информацию не в соответствии с вашей или моей  логикой, а в соответствии с ДЕЙСТВУЮЩИМИ ПРАВИЛАМИ ОРФОГРАФИИ, которые предлагает нам Грамота.ру. Загляните туда еще раз http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_68 ;

Comment: Цитирую Грамоту:
> **Как правило**, в этом случае [при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий *М. И.] после слов «(не) более / больше чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (час, грамм, километр и т. п.).

Выражение "как правило" означает, что чаще всего наблюдается так, но бывают исключения. Т.е. именно то, что я написал в ответе.

> Нейтральным вариантом будет "более чем на ...", но если хотите подчеркнуть, что именно "более", допустимо и "на более чем ..."

Пример: *Я думал об этом более чем друге дочери* Тут тоже неправильно предлог стоит?

Comment: Здесь выражение "как правило" обозначает только то, что выражение БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ обычно образует неразложимое сочетание с числовым оборотом, а в приведенных примерах ясно указано, что числовой оборот может иметь предложную падежную форму, при этом предлог всегда относится к числовому обороту, ни о какой перестановке предлога и речи нет.

Comment: А я привёл примеры из творчества Андрея Белого и Виктора Некрасова, где предлог переставлен. Ваши рассуждения о неразрывности предлога с существительным не выдерживают никакой критики, так как прилагательное ВСЕГДА разрывает эту "нерушимую" связь. Оборот "более чем" обычно не разрывает, но никаких причин для запрета подобного разрыва я не вижу. Ингода, см пример из комментария выше, по другому и не сформулировать.

Comment: Нацкорпус - это не учебник по грамматике и орфографии, из этого ресурса мы узнаем то, как писали, но не то, как надо писать, да и нормы могут меняться. Иногда отклонение от правила не очень заметно, вот в тексте и встречаются неточности. Кстати, у А. Белого в его  "на более чем аршин" используется В.п., поэтому такая форма и не привлекает к себе внимания. Не хочется навязываться со своей логикой, но дело в том, что здесь возникает конфликт двух падежей: числовой оборот имеет свой падеж, а слово "более" задает свой. Впрочем, Марк Из, мне нравится Ваша страстная убежденность в своей правоте.

Comment: София, объясните, пожалуйста, почему Вы говорите о правилах орфографии, а даете ссылку  при этом на правила пунктуации? Может, дадите ссылку на правила построения предложения с такими оборотами?

Comment: Наше правописание имеет грамматическую природу, поэтому грамматика часто регулирует и орфографию, и пунктуацию, как это можно видеть на данном примере: и отсутствие запятой, и  структура оборота объясняется тем, что перед нами неразложимое сочетание особого построения. Вообще-то ответ на вопрос дал Серж, он же привел ссылку на  Грамоту.ру. Казалось бы, зачем этот ответ редактировать? Я же просто подтвердила правильность ответа и попыталась ОБЪЯСНИТЬ ситуацию на основании общих сведений из Грамматики-80 о том, как компаратив управляет падежом. Сравните: три больше двух  и три больше чем два.

Comment: Ссылка Сержа тоже на пунктуационное правило.