# Место предлога НА: "более, чем на 50 участниках" или "на более, чем 50 участниках"?

Tags: синтаксис, предлоги

Проект и методики обучения уже были опробованы (на) более, чем (на) 50 участниках.

Comment: Подобные вопросы задавались неоднократно. См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434195/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-600-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb

Comment: Вот еще один: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Место предлога - как можно ближе к существительному. А запятая в данном предложении не нужна.

**Проект и методики обучения уже были опробованы более чем на 50 участниках.**

> [Вопрос № 269016](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=269016%20)
>   Как правильно: в более чем пятидесяти городах или более чем в пятидесяти городах. В соответствии с каким правилом (где об этом можно прочитать)? Благодарю за ответ.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   В «Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике» Д. Э. Розенталя отрыв предлога в подобного рода конструкциях назван «неудачным» (т. е. согласно справочнику лучше: более чем в пятидесяти городах).
>
> Обороты с союзом ЧЕМ отделяются запятой, если в предложении сравниваются или подразумеваются два понятия: "Шут необходим толпе более, чем герой" (М. Горький). "Поэт в России - больше, чем поэт" (Е. Евтушенко).
>   При отсутствии сравниваемых понятий мы имеем неразложимое словосочетание, после которого, как правило, следует количественно-именное сочетание: более чем в три раза. ([Запятая в выражении "более чем в три раза"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0/39535#39535))

Comment: Ваши ссылки, как всегда, к месту. Заценила.

Answer (score 4):

Естественен вариант "*более чем **на** 50 участниках*".

[Розенталь Дитмар Эльяшевич - Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати. Cтраница - 80](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=44687&page=80)

> *Неудачен отрыв предлога от управляемого существительного в*
>   *конструкциях типа: «Я приду с еще несколькими товарищами» (вместо:*
>   *"приду еще с несколькими товарищами")...*
>
> (Розенталь Дитмар Эльяшевич -
>   Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников
>   печати.)

Comment: Не нужна (нет сравнения) - не обратил внимания при копировании, спасибо.