# «Чем к большему» или «к чем большему»?

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, прилагательные

Как правильно сочетать оборот «чем.., тем» и прилагательное «больший» в дат. п.?

- *К чем* большему количеству сообществ вы присоединяетесь, тем сложнее становится отслеживать все свои вопросы;
- *чем к* большему количеству сообществ вы присоединяетесь, тем сложнее становится отслеживать все свои вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Чем** к большему количеству сообществ вы присоединяетесь, **тем** сложнее становится отслеживать все свои вопросы.

Двойной союз ЧЕМ...ТЕМ.

Пример: **Чем** к большему количеству слушателей вы обращаетесь, **тем** понятнее должен быть текст.

Answer (score 1):

Общий принцип состоит в том, что место предлога - как можно ближе к существительному. Например, корректно “более, чем на 50 участниках”, а не  “на более, чем 50 участниках”. (См.  [Место предлога НА: "более, чем на 50 участниках" или "на более, чем 50 участниках"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437621/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%90-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-50-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-50-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0/437624#437624))